# .htaccess to separate traffic to subdirectory with common folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have two websites on the same hosting, separated by two folders.
Then I have two domains pointing to the root.

I'm trying to create an htaccess rules that redirects "invisibly" one domain to one folder, and the other domain to the other folder.

But one tricky part is that I need to access the third folder from both domains.

This is the tree structure:

- site-A (for domain-A point)
- site-B (for domain-B point)
- common-Folder

Ex:

`http://domain-A/test` -> points and shows: site-A/test

`http://domain-B/test` -> points and shows: site-B/test

`http://domain-A/common` -> points and shows: common-Folder

`http://domain-B/common` -> points and shows: common-Folder

Is it possible to achive this structure using htaccess? How? Do I need to create something in between?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without any rewrite rules at present how is `common-Folder` accessed from a web browser?

Comment: If both domains are not on the same root folder or have any connection server side that will not be possible without completely redirecting or using a proxy

Comment: Both domains are pointing to the root folder. I want to redirect all calls for the correct folder (depending the domain used), and if someone try to access to /common, both will point to the common-folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain-A$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site-A/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site-A/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain-A$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /site-A/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain-B$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site-B/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site-B/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain-B$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /site-B/index.php [L]
```

Since we're ignoring folders and files in the rewrite condition, both can access to common-Folder.

If anyone have a better solution, i'm all "ears". But for now, this will work just fine.

Thank you all.